# Why is the Riemann integral for the sum-of-squares error function multiplied by the joint density function of the underlying distribution?

Tags: probability, riemann-sum, error-function

In Bishop's *Neural Networks for Pattern recognition* , he expresses an error function

$$ E= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k}\{(y_k(\mathbf{x}^{n};\mathbf{w})-t^{n}_{k}\}^2$$

where $\mathbf{x}^{n}$ is an instance vector from the dataset, $\mathbf{w}$ is the weight matrix of a hidden layer, $y_k(\mathbf{x}^{n};\mathbf{w})$ is the predicted or model's output, $t_{k}$ is the actual target value, $N$ is the size of training data, and $k$ indexes the outputs. He then multiplies by $\frac{1}{N}$, takes the limit as $N$ approaches infinity to find

$$ E= \lim_{N \to \infty }\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k}\{(y_k(\mathbf{x}^{n};\mathbf{w})-t^{n}_{k}\}^2$$

which is apparently

$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k}\int \int \{(y_k(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{w})-t_{k}\}^2
p(t_k,\mathbf{x}) \, dt_k \, d\mathbf{x}.$$

Why does the Riemann integral get multiplied by the underlying probability distribution  $p(t_k,\mathbf{x})$ ?